# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LpProblem'

Tags: python, pulp

I am trying to use Pulp on mac. When i run the code below, it shows the error that follows:

Code (part of it):

```
# import the library pulp as p 
import pulp as p 
# Create a LP Minimization problem 
Lp_prob = p.LpProblem('Problem', p.LpMinimize)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pulp.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pulp as p 
  File "/Users/gauravmogra/Desktop/pulp/pulp.py", line 5, in <module>
    Lp_prob = p.LpProblem('Problem', p.LpMinimize)  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LpProblem'
```

Comment: Try renaming your directory/file to something other than `pulp`/`pulp.py`

Comment: what IDE are you using? is that pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

As afghanimah suggests, the problem is in the fact that you try to import a package named "pulp", while your working directory and Python script are also named "pulp". Rename your directory and "pulp.py" script to anything than "pulp".